# Magento2: How to rename the Details tab on the product details page, via overwriting layout file?

Tags: magento2, product, layout, xml

How can I use arguments in an xml layout file to **overwrite the Details tab title on the product details page?** The layout file I hope to overwrite is: vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml
The block in the file is:
[image]

Answer (score 10):

In `app/design/frontend/[Package]/[Yourtheme]/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml`:

```
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.details">                
            <referenceBlock name="product.info.description">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Description</argument>
                </arguments>
            </referenceBlock>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

If you want to add a new tab, i.e attribute how_to_use:

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Attributes" name="product.info.how_to_use" template="product/view/attribute.phtml" group="detailed_info">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="at_call" xsi:type="string">getHowToUse</argument>
                <argument name="at_code" xsi:type="string">how_to_use</argument>
                <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">details-how-to-use</argument>
                <argument name="at_label" xsi:type="string">none</argument>
                <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">How to use</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
```

Answer (score 4):

In your custom layout file you can call the following:

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info.description">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Custom Name</argument>
    </arguments>
</referenceBlock>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    <referenceBlock name="product.info.description">
        <action method="setTitle">
            <argument name="title" xsi:type="string">NewTitleGoesHere</argument>
        </action>
    </referenceBlock>
```